# Scipy 1D smooth preserving edges

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have an array which I want to apply a 1d gaussian filter to using Scipy's gaussian_filter1d without changing the edge values:

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d
>>> arr = [1.,2.,3.,4.,100.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.]
```

However this fails to preserve edge values 1 and 10:

```
>>> gaussian_filter1d(arr, 5, mode="nearest")
>>> array([  8.26708045,   9.54770677,  10.72077793,  11.70511557,
            12.43900171,  12.89021341,  13.06040738,  12.98285813,
            12.71434815,  12.32350223,  11.87856682])
```

Answer (score 0):

This method seems needlessly complicated, however this smooths the gradient rather than the values themselves:

```
# Convolve with sobel filter
grad = convolve(arr, [1,-1,0], mode="nearest")[:-1]
# Smooth gradient
smooth_grad = smooth_grad = gaussian_filter1d(grad, 5)
# Integrate
smoothed = [arr[0] + sum(smooth_grad[:x]) for x in range(len(arr))]
```

Producing:

```
[1.0, 3.6, 6.0, 9.6, 10.7, 11.3, 11.5,11.2,10.7,10.0]
```